# HttpNotificationChannel doesn't want to create new channel Uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I have a weird situation and I'm stuck.
I created push notification in my WindowsPhone application.
After some time my channelUri has expired and now I can't create new one, because the code responsible for that returns the same invalid channel Uri.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
_pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName); //returns null

            if (null == _pushChannel)
            {
                _pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);  //returns channel with expired channelUri
                _pushChannel.Open();
            }
```

I also tried using Close() method, but it didn't help anyway.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When a channel expires and a new one is issued **you will normally get the same URI back**. This is to be expected.

What will be different is that the channel will be been enabled again.  If you discover that when you next send to a notification the channel is reported as expired then check what you are sending as invalid payloads will cause the channel to expire when upon sending.